# Accessing External IP from LAN

Tags: networking

This is my first Question. Sorry if its not on the proper site.

I work @ a software company and we're having trouble accesing the External IP from LAN.
we have a Modem/Router ADB PDG A4001N. We use this modem as the main router. We also have a server running on Windows Server 2008. All the ports that we need are forwarded to a Static LAN IP that belongs to the server. 
We have a particular problem.
When we try to access for example FTP or HTTP site hosted in the server from the lan IP (EX: 192.168.1.121/Index.html) we have no problem. Also accesing from the outside is no problem (ex: mysite.no-ip.org (we're not paying for domains). The problem occurs when we try to reach the external IP from LAN. If we try to access via http or FTP to the external IP it redirect us to the modem own HTTP Site or FTP site. It not only happens with these two services, it looks like its not doing Port Forward correctly when accessing external ip from lan. Any hint?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you using stock firmware? Is it possible to login to router via telnet or ssh?

Comment: I haven't been able to connect via SSH neither telnet, and FTP. Using default admin password (the same i use to access admin configuration from http), even tried with most common default usr/pass combinations, the ftp give me the chance to input user/password but im automatically rejected from ssh & telnet connections, even though they are enabled from the advanced configuration.Im starting to think that the modem may be broken. A week earlier i could access to the external ip from LAN. The only that changed was few more PortForwards but I've already deleted them.

Comment: and yes its using stock firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is not up to the task you have for it. this device is designed for home consumers and does not support a feature called hairpin nat, which allows an internal request to the public IP to be routed out of your network and then back in through the NAT rules you have established.

what you are experiencing is that your requests to the external interface of the router and being handled by the internal interface which does not implement NAT, so your packets are not redirected to the server by your forward rules, and are instead getting responses from the internal services your device provides.

Comment: This really does make sense, but what it not make sense it that previously was working perfectly fine. I know its a home router and im not expecting too much from it, but the problem started when i've made several adds and remove in the forward table... I have access to nat forwarding to the server address but that doesn't solve anything.